# cocos2dx When I set setPhysicsBody to sprite, sprite gone

Tags: c++, animation, cocos2d-x, sprite, collision

I'm new on `cocos2dx`, and It's probably a silly mistake,

I made animation to my sprite and it worked. Then I add `PhysicsBody` to my sprite for collisions. After that When I start game, Sprite wasn't on screen and I didn't get any error. I checked gravity twice. My code is here

```
CCSpriteFrameCache* frameCache = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache();
frameCache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("RedFurryFall.plist");
CCSpriteBatchNode* spriteSheet = CCSpriteBatchNode::create("RedFurryFall.png");
this->addChild(spriteSheet);
Vector<SpriteFrame*> RedFurryFallFrames(4);
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    CCString * fileName = CCString::createWithFormat("RedFurryFall%d.png", i);
    CCSpriteFrame* frame = CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache()->spriteFrameByName(fileName->getCString());
    RedFurryFallFrames.pushBack(frame);
}

CCAnimation* runAnim = CCAnimation::createWithSpriteFrames(RedFurryFallFrames, 0.15);
CCSprite* redFurry = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("RedFurryFall1.png");

CCSize winSize = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
redFurry->setPosition(ccp(winSize.width*0.5, winSize.height*0.85));
redFurry->setScale(0.50);

auto physicsBody = PhysicsBody::createCircle(redFurry->getContentSize().width/2, PhysicsMaterial(0.1, 1, 0));
physicsBody->setDynamic(false);
physicsBody->setGravityEnable(false);
redFurry->setPhysicsBody(physicsBody);

CCAction*action = CCRepeatForever::create(CCAnimate::create(runAnim));
redFurry->runAction(action);
spriteSheet->addChild(redFurry);
```

When I remove this`redFurry->setPhysicsBody(physicsBody);` I can see my sprite on screen. I couldn't figure what's wrong with that. Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: You can enable debug frames for physic bodies and for sprites. But most probably something goes wrong with physics and position of the sprite. So I recomment set a breakpoint and take a look at the position of the sprite you need.

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue before (although I was using box2D). Physics engines use meters as their metric and not pixels, so setting your physicsBody position to screenWidth/2 is going to place it very far off screen. I suggest you do something like below.

```
float PTM_RATIO = 32.0; // Pixel to meter ratio
auto physicsBodyPosition = vec2((winSize.width*0.5) / PTM_RATIO,
                                (winSize.height*0.5) / PTM_RATIO);
```

Let me know if this helps.